# Session node js

Tags: nodejs, kubernetes

alguien me echa una mano por favor, tengo un minikube con 3 replicas para un StatefulSet de mysql y un servicio de mysql, 3 replicas para un Deployment de mi app de node, la app se conecta a la BD sin problema, pero no me loguea a la app, haber si os hago un resumen.

Cuando inicio session, me sale el mensaje de que he logueado, pero sin embargo la pagina que me muestra sigue siendo el login, con el boton de loguear etc etc.

Esto pasa cuando tengo 3 replicas, pero si construyo el deployment con una replica no tengo ese problema, me logueo sin problemas.

Entonces intento entender es problema de mi APP en NODE o de minikube?

contenedores que uso       APP : lopuma/liburutegia:1.4, y BD : lopuma/db-liburutegia:1.0

```
    $ k get all -o wide
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/db-liburutegia-0               1/1     Running   0          13h   172.17.0.3    minikube   <none>           <none>
pod/db-liburutegia-1               1/1     Running   0          25m   172.17.0.9    minikube   <none>           <none>
pod/db-liburutegia-2               1/1     Running   0          25m   172.17.0.10   minikube   <none>           <none>
pod/liburutegia-7cccdd78dc-phm88   1/1     Running   0          23m   172.17.0.11   minikube   <none>           <none>

NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
service/db-liburutegia    ClusterIP   10.110.60.178   <none>        3306/TCP         13h   app=db-liburutegia
service/kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          13h   <none>
service/svc-liburutegia   NodePort    10.107.100.80   <none>        3000:30000/TCP   13h   role=liburutegia

NAME                          READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS    IMAGES                   SELECTOR
deployment.apps/liburutegia   1/1     1            1           13h   application   lopuma/liburutegia:1.4   app=liburutegia,role=liburutegia

NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE     CONTAINERS    IMAGES                   SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/liburutegia-7cccdd78dc   1         1         1       23m     application   lopuma/liburutegia:1.4   app=liburutegia,pod-template-hash=7cccdd78dc,role=liburutegia
replicaset.apps/liburutegia-7ff7c49f8d   0         0         0       4h28m   application   lopuma/liburutegia:1.4   app=liburutegia,pod-template-hash=7ff7c49f8d,role=liburutegia

NAME                              READY   AGE   CONTAINERS       IMAGES
statefulset.apps/db-liburutegia   3/3     13h   db-liburutegia   lopuma/db-liburutegia:1.0
```

**MANIFIESTO DE LA BD**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: db-liburutegia
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: "db-liburutegia"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db-liburutegia
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db-liburutegia
    spec:
      nodeName: minikube
      containers:
      - name: db-liburutegia
        image: lopuma/db-liburutegia:1.0
        ports:
        - name: tpc
          protocol: TCP
          containerPort: 3306
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: "sanmiguel"
          - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            value: "*******"
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: "*******"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql-store
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mysql-store
      spec:
        storageClassName: standard
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
```

**SERVICIO MYSQL**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db-liburutegia
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  #clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: db-liburutegia
```

**MANIFIESTO DE APP**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  #creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: liburutegia
  name: liburutegia
spec:
  #progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  #revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: liburutegia
      app: liburutegia
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: liburutegia
        app: liburutegia
    spec:
      nodeName: minikube
      containers:
      - name: application
        image: lopuma/liburutegia:1.4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP
        env:
          - name: NODE_ENV
            value: "production"
          - name: NODE_PORT
            value: '3000'
          - name: MYSQL_HOST
            value: "db-liburutegia" #AQUI VA EL SERVICIO DE MYSQL
          - name: MYSQL_USER
            value: "root"
          - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            value: "*****"
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: "******"
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: "sanmiguel"
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada réplica guarda tu sesión. Debes de habilitar la affinidad para que el service te mande al mismo pod en cada petición.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
```